# noise in house 24/7

Tags: walls

if anyone can help me I would be more than grateful to compensate.  No matter which room I go to upstairs downstairs including the basement my house has this wavy humming sound constantly 24/7. I’ll check with Hydro I also turn the entire power off in the house it’s still there
It’s not the plumbing either someone please help identify what possibly is causing this

Comment: Are you sure it's not in your head?  Seriously, some types of tinnitus sound like this.  It's often masked outside because there is more background noise.  Try some earplugs and see if that makes and difference.

Comment: Quiet can make tinnitus worse (for some) I have hearing aides that produce a noise I can’t hear well but it helps. I was thinking of other things like is the home over or close to a water main under a power line. Do any of your neighbors hear it?

Comment: Do other people hear it? More telling, do you stop hearing it when there's other people? ... [Tinnitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus) - Ima guess you live alone and you're over the age of 35.

Answer (score 0):

I live near a utility power substation and at certain times of year, the different levels of moisture in the ground allow humming vibrations from the transformers to be heard in the house, especially at bed time when everything else it off. I have learned to live with it.

And for the smart-alecs, yes, I have tried teaching it the words so that it doesn't have to hum...